# If $f\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n}\right)\neq\lim_{n\to \infty}f (x_{n})$, can we say that $f$ does not have a lim at $x_{n}$'s convergent point?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Assume $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to +\infty}}x_{n}$ $=$ $c$.
 If we have $f\left(\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to +\infty}}x_{n}\right)$ $\neq$ $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to +\infty}}f\left(x_{n}\right)$ can we say that $f$ does not have a limit at $x_{n}$'s convergent point which is c?

I was reading solution manual to Real Analysis by Bartle & Sherbert 4th edition and this 
unequal equation was used and I was wondering how to prove the correctness.

I know that if we want to show that a function does not have a limit at point $p$, we propose a sequence $y_{n}$ such that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to +\infty}}y_{n}=p$ & $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to +\infty}}f\left(x_{n}\right)$ does not exit. (Sequential Criterion)

Comment: I would just say that $f$ is not continuous at $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$, assuming that limit exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot, though you can say that $f$ is not continuous at $c$. Let $x_n=\frac1n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}x_n=0$. Let

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x=0\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Then $f(0)\ne\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$, but $f$ certainly does have a limit at $0$: $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposition is of the form
$$P \; and \; Q \; \implies \; R$$

it is equivalent to
$$P \; and \; \lnot R \; \implies \; \lnot Q$$
which means

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=c \; and \; \lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L \; \implies \; \lim_{n\to +\infty}f(x_n)=f(c)$$

This is obviously true only if $L=f(c)$.